# Extent Report TestRunner Log View : is it removed from version 4 or can we enable?

Tags: java, extentreports

I am using this jar and it has the method available to add TestNg/Junit log in Extent report TestRunner Log View

```
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>4.0.9</version>
```

Or can we enable the log view somehow. ? Below old version having log view.
http://relevantcodes.com/Tools/ExtentReports2/ExtentJava.html

In API doc , i can still see this method :
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/javadoc/com/aventstack/extentreports/ExtentReports.html

```
for (String s : Reporter.getOutput()) {
   extent.setTestRunnerOutput(s);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature will be available v5.0 onwards. See issue https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/issues/157

The SNAPSHOT release is available for you to use with the new default Spark reporter.